# SQL Server Paging and Holy Grail

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, pagination

I am looking into doing some efficient paging and found this link that says the "Holy Grail" is the best approach.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/

Is the table just being used as an example, or is it actually part of the solution.  What I mean is how would you do this with a table that has many joins, same approach?  Can someone post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table "[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].columns" is just being used as an example.

I'd use the same approach for a table that has many joins. Just make sure you have proper indexes.

"Holy Grial" solution just gives you paged results plus a column indicating the total of rows, without overhead. You can get the total of rows on another query.

Be aware of the article conclusion's:

> ....this approach to be best suited for smaller resultsets from complex
>   queries where I/O is the primary bottleneck. Jeff Moden, Peso and
>   others here have pointed out that with larger resultsets, the I/O cost
>   you save is more than outweighed by the CPU cost.

Comment: So to get this performance boost, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name, column_name) AS seq, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name DESC, column_name desc) AS totrows, two row_numbers going in reverse order is what I need?

Comment: Yes. That's just to reduce overhead. Just one query to get the paged results and the total number of rows. Example: "Products" table has 5000 rows. I want to see page 20, having 100 rows. That'd be row 1901 to 2000. Using ROW_NUMBER() twice in the same query, you can get the total number of rows (5000). Other way, you'd have to write another query for that.